# Redirect example.com to www.example.com using Heroku (rails) and Cloudflare

Tags: heroku, cloudflare

How would one setup a redirect from example.com to www.example.com using Heroku and Cloudflare?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not something that you can do at CloudFlare since they now host the DNS for your domain and don't support redirects so it's something you'd have to do at the application level.

http://support.cloudflare.com/discussions/questions/259-redirect-to-www

Comment: Hey John. Does this (new) capability things? https://support.cloudflare.com/entries/22041842-how-do-i-do-url-forwarding-with-cloudflare

Comment: @john-beynon That might have been true when this answer was posted but it isn't anymore because a common feature included in CloudFlare are page rules, which let a user set up redirection very easily

Comment: absolutely, it looks like the page rules are a now a great solution to the problem.

Answer (score 3):

One free way to do it is to use the [Naked Domain Redirect from wwwizer.com](http://wwwizer.com/naked-domain-redirect). You just make an A record for example.com to 174.129.25.170 (you can do that from Cloudflare). wwwizer will then redirect the request to www.example.com. It's probably the easiest way that I know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet here is to do the redirect with something like [Rack-rewrite](https://github.com/jtrupiano/rack-rewrite), or at the DNS level  if you're hosting DNS on [Zerigo](http://www.zerigo.com/managed-dns).